# how to do custom global filtering on the react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table-v7

for eg. I have covid data and I display it in the react table it contains the columns like continent, country, new cases, total cases, active cases, deaths etc. now I want to do filtering on the table where it returns row if I enter county or continent name if I enter any other key in input field it should not return anything in the table just show result not found.

global filter function:

```
function GlobalFilter({filter, setFilter}) {
    const[value, setValue] = useState(filter);

    const onChange = useAsyncDebounce((value)=>{
        setFilter(value || undefined);
    }, 1000);

    return (
        <div className='filter'>
            <input value={filter || ''} onChange={(e)=>{
                setFilter(e.target.value) 
                onChange(e.target.value)}} placeholder='Enter Country or Continent'/>
        </div>
```

column of the table:

```
 COLUMNS = [
    {
        Header : 'Continent',
        accessor : 'continent',
    },
    {
        Header : 'Country',
        accessor : 'country',
    },
    {
        Header : 'Total Cases',
        accessor : 'totalcases',
    },
    {
        Header : 'Active Cases',
        accessor : 'activecases',
    },
    {
        Header : 'Total Recovery',
        accessor : 'recovery',
    },
    {
        Header : 'Total Death',
        accessor : 'deaths',
    },
    {
        Header : 'New Cases',
        accessor : 'newcases',
    },
```

]

Comment: Keep all your data in a state, create a new variable `filteredItems` (no need for it to be a state). Assign `filteredItems` the results of your filter function. Pass `filteredItems` to the Table component.

Comment: i want to do it by entering the value in the input tag

Comment: you would read the value from your input in your filter function. In there you decide what should be in the table. When you want to filter by country or continent, you have filter your data by that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do this:

```
const CovidData = () => {
 const [data, setData] = useState([//your data goes here])
 const [filter, setFilter] = useState(null) //null = show all items

 const filteredItems = filter ? data.filter(elem => elem.country === filter) : data

 return (
  <>
    <input onChange={e => setFilter(e.target.value)} />
    <TableComp items={filteredItems} />
  </>
 )
}
```

This is untested, but you should get the gist :)